# Plasmon quenching vs plasmon decay. What is the difference?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, spectroscopy, molecules, plasmon

I'm reading an article "Quenching, Plasmonic, and Radiative Decays in Nanogap Emitting Devices" (pubs.acs.org/journal/apchd5).

I don't understand the following:

> Counterintuitively, we evidence that the key
>   parameters are the material permittivities and not the gap
>   thickness and that the gap plasmon decay surpasses the
>   quenching decay for nanogaps fed with high-refractive-index
>   materials and molecules polarized perpendicular to the gap
>   interfaces.

What is gap plasmon decay and how does it differ from quenching decay for nanogaps?